как добавить платформу на Unity 6?
итак, скачал Unity 6 (6000.0.24f1) и со временем понадобилась поддержка Android, захотел как обычно поставить как делал всегда (шестерёнка -> configure) но этой кнопки в новом юнити хабе нет
вопрос как добавить платформу не переустанавливая весь движок?

изменено: Module download не помогает, пишет что не установлен движок


Если, что я не обвиняю - я предлагаю!

Что вам мешает перейти на новую версию?

Вы можете как на скрине?


Нажмите Switch Platform

Лучше конечно перейти на новую версию.

Всегда проверяйте перед началом создания проекта доступна ли
платформа.

Повторюсь - это не в обиду!

проблема с тем что установить платформу не выходит (ошибка: cannot found UNITY 6 or below), решилась тем что просто поставил более новую версию Unity
